# How to have an Excel cell displays a number (unique to each cell) when no data is entered?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not sure if this is possible. I need certain Excel Cells to display a number (unique to each cell) when I haven't entered any data in the cell. Its used to assign sites on a 'map/list' and I want them to have a number when no one has been assigned the site.

Comment: more info and an example.   I want a cell to show the number '1' ..   Susan now wants to have Site 1 so i write her name in that cell ... It now shows SUSAN.  She changes her mind and i remove her name and the cell again shows 1.   is this even possible? or would entering the name susan remove the formula(or whatever)?

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to maintain two lists:
[image]

in column A, let's say you have the total number of the columns 1 to 10 and in front of each you put down any corresponding name.
 then in another sheet or column, you maintain your results site list, that is column E. But using a very simple formula:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(B2),B2,A2)
```

put this formula in E2 and drag down until the end, then where you have names, then the names will appear otherwise the number, and if you remove the name from column B, then the name cells on E will revert to numbers, taken from A.
I hope this simple solution comes in handy.